# Navigation Stack empty when navigating from TabbedPage (Back button missing)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, maui

I am having an issue where I have no `NavigationBar` on my page and this only happened after I implemented Tabbed pages in .NET MAUI with the Prism MVVM framework. Any help is much appreciated.

All the pages being shown and their view models have been registered as services.

**Code to navigate to Tabbed page**:

```cs
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(HomePage)}?{KnownNavigationParameters.SelectedTab}={nameof(DashboardPage)}");
```

**TabbedPage**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="TestApp.Views.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp.Views;assembly=TestApp"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    AutomationId="home_page">

    <local:DashboardPage x:Name="dashboardPage" Title="Home" IconImageSource="icon_home_o" />
    <local:CommentListPage x:Name="commentListPage" Title="Comments" IconImageSource="icon_comment_o" />
    <local:MorePage x:Name="morePage" Title="More" IconImageSource="icon_ellipsis_o" />
</TabbedPage>
```

**Dashboard page view model** (code navigating to another new view):

```cs
//When the navigation happens, this page has NO navigation bar and this NO BACK BUTTON which is a problem
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(TestListPage))
```

**TestListPage initialisation**:

```cs
public partial class TestListPage : ContentPage
{
    public TestListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //nav stack has a count of 0
        var test = Navigation.NavigationStack;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        //nav stack has a count of 0
        var test = Navigation.NavigationStack;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having an issue where I have no `NavigationBar` on my page and this only happened after I implemented Tabbed pages in .NET MAUI with the Prism MVVM framework.

I tested the code, and as you described that. You can [report it to GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues). In addition, you have to use Prism MVVM framework? Can CommunityToolkit.Mvvm achieve your needs?

About Navigation, there're some tips for it:

> While a `NavigationPage` can be placed in a `TabbedPage`, it's not recommended to place a `TabbedPage` into a `NavigationPage`.

> `TabbedPage` is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception will be thrown if you attempt to use `TabbedPage` in a Shell app.

For more details you can refer to the official doc: [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-7.0).

**Update:**

According to what steve says:

> A workaround I did was instead of putting `NavigateAsync(nameof(TestListPage))`. I put `NavigateAsync($"/{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(HomePage)}/{nameof(TestListPage)}")`.

It can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering me! A workaround I did was instead of putting `NavigateAsync(nameof(TestListPage))` I put `NavigateAsync($"/{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(HomePage)}/{nameof(TestListPage)}")` incase anyone else needs help

Comment: @steve Nice!  I update the answer according to your comment.